# Screen becoming black when moving from one tab bar to another

Tags: ios, ios7

My Program has a tab bar view controller containing two tabs. each tab contains a table and when clicking on each cell, a new view is loaded. But when i go back to the main view after going into the cell, the screen becomes black. I can move to the other tab now but the same process repeats.Can someone please tell me why this is happening ??

Comment: When you say `view`, do you mean `ViewController`? There is a significant difference.

Comment: show the code, please… what you do to go to the main view?

Comment: Did you have give Individual Navigation Controller to all your Tabs?

Comment: Please provide some code or console error/warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Tableviewcontroller is embed in NavigationController.
Follow this tutorial
http://www.appcoda.com/storyboard-tutorial-create-tab-bar-controller-and-web-view/

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your parent view is unloading from the memory.